# ggsurvplot - remove "censored" mark from legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing survival curves using `ggsurvplot` in `survminer` package and I need to have the "censored" marks present in the graph, but not in a legend - it covers the line type and makes it indistinguishable in a case of black and white image.

So far I have only a workaround - make the legend wider. But that's inconvenient since the whole legend would get too wide (My real labels are also longer)

I've also tried setting `shape = F` in `guides()`, with no success.

Minimal example would be this: [(resulting image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06pTl.png)

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, palette = "jco", 
           linetype = c("solid", "longdash", "dotted", "dotdash", "dashed"),
           legend = "right", legend.title = "Why U no work?!", legend.labs = 1:4)+
    guides(color = guide_legend(keywidth = 2, keyheight = 1.8))
```

Also - widening the legend seems to work only when specifying color palette, why is that?

Comment: You should be able to use `override.aes` in `guide_legend` to remove shapes: `override.aes = list(shape = NA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aosmith solved that!

key is use `override.aes =` in `guide_legend()`.

It has to be a **list** of aesthetics, hence `list(shape = NA)`.
I missed that when trying to solve it by myself.

Thanks aosmith!
(just posting this so that it can be marked as solved)